# How to get the correct ResolutionScale in a Windows 8 Store App?

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, scale, screen-resolution

i'm working on a Windows 8 Store App and i am trying to use different icon resolutions for different screen sizes.

But somehow

```
ResolutionScale resolutionScale = Windows.Graphics.Display.DisplayProperties.ResolutionScale;
```

always returns Scale100Percent. I tried it on my Desktop PC, which runs at 1080p and i also tried it with the simulator in all different resolutions it offers but the ResolutionScale Property stays 100%.

Using DisplayInformation instead of DisplayProperties is not an option because i still want to support Windows 8.0.

Does anyone know if there is another way to get the current resolution scale in Windows 8.0 or if i am doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance

Khrimm

Edit: Using the actual screen resolution to determine the scale factor seems to be another possibility.

Comment: I hope this will be help => http://programmerpayback.com/2013/08/31/detecting-screen-resolution-in-windows-8-and-windows-phone-apps/

Comment: The link helped. Thanks